# rsyslog logging same data to multiple files

Tags: unix, syslog, rsyslog

I'm new to configuring rsyslog for centralized logging and was wondering if one of you experts could help me with the following problem.  I am trying to store logs for each remote host to a per host directory.  This is working just fine with the exception of maillog.  For some reason the maillog goes into the defined directory for the specific host but also gets written for all the hosts running mail to /var/log/maillog.

Is there a specific config somewhere that would be causing the logs to be written in multiple places?

Here is my remote-hosts.conf file

```
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514
$DirGroup root
$DirCreateMode 0755
$FileGroup root
$template PerHostAuth,"/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/auth.log"
$template PerHostCron,"/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/cron.log"
$template PerHostSyslog,"/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/syslog"
$template PerHostDaemon,"/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/daemon.log"
$template PerHostKern,"/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/kern.log"
$template PerHostLpr,"/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/lpr.log"
$template PerHostUser,"/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/user.log"
$template PerHostMail,"/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/mail.log"
$template PerHostMailInfo,"/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/mail.info"
$template PerHostMailWarn,"/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/mail.warn"
$template PerHostMailErr,"/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/mail.err"
$template PerHostNewsCrit,"/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/news.crit"
$template PerHostNewsErr,"/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/news.err"
$template PerHostNewsNotice,"/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/news.notice"
$template PerHostDebug,"/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/debug"
$template PerHostMessages,"/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/messages"
auth,authpriv.*         ?PerHostAuth
*.*;auth,authpriv.none  -?PerHostSyslog
cron.*                  ?PerHostCron
daemon.*                -?PerHostDaemon
kern.*                  -?PerHostKern
lpr.*                   -?PerHostLpr
mail.*                  -?PerHostMail
user.*                  -?PerHostUser
mail.info               -?PerHostMailInfo
mail.warn               ?PerHostMailWarn
mail.err                ?PerHostMailErr
news.crit               ?PerHostNewsCrit
news.err                ?PerHostNewsErr
news.notice             -?PerHostNewsNotice
*.=debug;\
   auth,authpriv.none;\
   news.none;mail.none   -?PerHostDebug
   *.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
      auth,authpriv.none;\
      cron,daemon.none;\
      mail,news.none        -?PerHostMessages
```

So what is happening is I have logs going to /var/log/maillog for **ALL** of my mail servers that are sending logs via syslog in addition to their individual directories under

```
/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/Host1/mail.log 
/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/Host2/mail.log
/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/Host3/mail.log
/srv/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/Host4/mail.log
```

What is the correct way to stop logs from being written to maillog for remote systems?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Maybe just ignore it? mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog